# Where is it possible to use a hammock in the UK?

Tags: uk, hammock

I have a hennessy hammock which is great, but so far I have always taken my tent along too... as it is rare that campsites have trees the correct distance apart, or let you pick a pitch with the few trees on the site.

Is there a list of campsites that cater for hammock use?

Also I would like to do some wild camping, but a pretty strong factor in English wild lands is a lack of trees! Is there a resource that lists good areas to try?

Comment: I have so far rather preferred to carry/pack the things that I may require for a trek/hike/camping, and not the other way round, by deciding where to go with this particular set of things I have.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. I want to know where I can go with the particular set of things I have... that is exactly what I am asking...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet is to study an Ordance Survey map of the area. Incidently [you can get these off Bing](http://binged.it/1j00Hj9) which is cool.

I'd look for a campsite symbol [image] with some form of forest near by: [image]

Preferably deciduous forest, which will have well spaced out trees, forestry commision land tends to be densely packed:

[image]

The same applies for any wild camping spots. Bear in mind wild camping isn't particularly legal in the UK (excluding Scotland where it is legal), though it is generally tolerated.

On another note, I have a hammock and I have rock climbing anchors. You can suspend a hammock quite well from quarry's, etc. if you put good anchors in...not at height obviously!

[image]

---

If your after specifics I'd say [Low Wray on Windermere](http://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/holidays/camping/camping-in-the-lake-district/low-wray/) would be perfect for your needs:

[image]

### [Map link](http://binged.it/1j0beee)

Comment: What area are you thinking?

Comment: I don't want to turn this into too much of a specific chat relevant only to me... but I am London based and don't drive so around the South East for absolute preference... but I love the lakes and the peaks (and other treeless places it seems!)

Comment: Only one that springs to mind is the [Low Wray](http://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/holidays/camping/camping-in-the-lake-district/low-wray/) national trust camp site by windermere. The lake side pitches are basically in mixed forest and would be perfect for what you want,

Comment: @Loofer http://www.blackberrywood.com/index.php accept Hammocks, might too commercial for you but is South of London on the train [Hassock or Plumpton] (Streat Nr Ditchling, Sussex)

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to Liams answer:

Plan your trip and search for natural campsites (so don't go for the busy familily and tourist ones).
I found they mostly have two parts, one open-ish field and a forest part with 'normal' tree spacing.
Since I mostly go car camping I will often hang one side of my hammock of the roof of my jeep thus requiring one less tree.

You should also consider using a tree protector of some sorts (a dirty t-shirt does the trick), this get's any tree huggers at ease.
People (and most importantly the grounds keeper) never seem to mind it that much, they'll more often be intrigued about my setup then annoyed.

Happy camping!

Comment: I talked to "Camping in the Forest" and they don't allow hammocks :( Maybe better to ask forgiveness than permission ;)

Answer (score 4):

I have found that the forestry commission runs 'private' forests too. We should call them woodlands I suppose. However, to the question. The trees may have been planted methodically in neat lines but some saplings die. I have slept in the woodlands around Macclesfield and found some of the more mature trees to be too far apart, even the pines. I use tree huggers as they are quick and cause no damage to the bark.

As far as being seen is concerned I tested this out with a double duvet cover strung vertically between two trees. It was a white and yellow pattern. I stood alongside with a coffee and no interest was shown by either people, their dogs, children or horses. 
Look and ask around most people are helpful and will often make suggestions.

Give it a try. Being woken by deer or the early morning chorus is worth the effort.
p.s. I'm 70 so if I can enjoy it so can you.
Peter